# Change log file path in solr 2.6

Tags: solr, lucidworks

Our default log file path in solr 2.6 is C:\Program Files\LucidWorks\V2.6\data\logs.

Due to the space issue in c drive, Iwould like to change this path to another drive in the same server. Like 'D:\Solr\Logs'.

Is it possible??

Thanks in Advance!!

Varun

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you're using v2.6 of LucidWorks Search, which is based on Solr 4.4.

The question is also specific to their setup, which is a modified bundled that uses Solr as it backend. [The documentation (if you search for logging)](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/lweug27/System+Directories+and+Logs) that was added for 2.7 says that most of the paths are configurable through arguments to `start.bat`.

```
-lwe_log_dir    ($LWS_HOME/data/logs/ as default)
```

Although it's a 2.7 setting, I'm guessing it would work for 2.6 as well. Otherwise, check the start.bat file to see if you have a setting there.